# I can’t open my projects through wampserver?

Tags: html, wampserver

I tried using wampserver for a Phaser game. I want to open my projects through it but it doesn’t open.

[image: These are your folders in c:/wamp64/www To use them as an http link, you must declare them as VirtualHost]

It says, “These are your folders in c:/wamp64/www
To use them as an http link, you must declare them as VirtualHost”

What is the problem?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server cover your issue?